# Order results by date in second table

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

a bit of background...

I currently have a client area for clients to login and see their job's progress and leave any comments etc. In the client area, I have an admin area where it enables me to login and view all of the jobs. Everything is working fine, but i'd like to be able to sort it a bit neater.

The database consists of 4 tables, 2 of these are relevant to this query... Jobs and Posts. Currently the list just shows a full list of jobs for every client using the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Jobs ORDER BY date DESC");
```

Then:

```
<a href="jobdetail.php?clientid='. $row['ClientID'].'&jobid='.$row['JobNumber'].'">'. $row['Username'].' - '. $row['ClientID'].'.'.$row['JobNumber'].' - '.$row['Description'].' - '.$row['Status'].'</a>
```

As you can see, the details are taken from the database and echoed, and the whole thing is then linked to the page that loads the job from their ClientID and JobNumber. All client's can have a job number 1 eg ClientID: 12345 and ClientID: 12346 can both have JobNumber1. At the moment this all works fine, but i'd like to have the the Job that has the newest post related to it in the Posts table at the top, and then the next newest, and so on.

At the moment after some research i've got to this:

```
SELECT
Jobs.*
FROM Jobs
LEFT JOIN Posts ON Posts.JobNumber=Jobs.JobNumber
GROUP BY
Jobs.ClientID, Jobs.JobNumber
ORDER BY Posts.PostDate
```

And whilst I am getting all of the results, I am not getting them in order of the date of the post. I have a feeling it is because i'm not actually pulling the PostDate value from the Posts table, but i've tried loads and i'm not managing to get anything to work!

If anyone could give me any pointers it'd be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is intended to be used with aggregate functions on all non-GROUPBY columns.  MySQL is forgiving about this but returns a random selection of values in the non-GROUPBY columns.  I seriously doubt this is what you want.

Comment: I'm getting a normal return of values with:

    `SELECT
    Jobs.*
    FROM Jobs
    LEFT JOIN Posts ON Posts.JobNumber=Jobs.JobNumber
    GROUP BY
    Jobs.ClientID, Jobs.JobNumber
    ORDER BY Posts.PostDate`

But it's not sorting in order, but the result I get from the code suggested below is just completely scrambled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working:

```
SELECT
c.ClientID
, j.JobNumber , j.Username , j.Description , j.ClientID , j.Status , j.AdminUnread
, MAX(p.PostDate) as postedOn
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN Jobs j ON c.ClientID=j.ClientID
LEFT JOIN Posts p ON j.JobNumber=p.JobNumber AND c.ClientID=p.ClientID
GROUP BY
c.ClientID
, j.JobNumber
ORDER BY
postedOn DESC, c.ClientID, j.JobNumber DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Jobs j 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT p.* 
             FROM posts p 
             INNER JOIN (SELECT JobNumber, MAX(postdate) postdate 
                         FROM posts GROUP BY jobnumber
                        ) a ON p.JobNumber = a.JobNumber AND a.postdate = p.postdate
           ) p ON p.JobNumber = j.JobNumber 
GROUP BY j.ClientID, j.JobNumber 
ORDER BY p.PostDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but now it's completely scrambling all of the results in the list and I can't make out what it is actually outputting. The Client Names and ID's etc are all over the place with the wrong titles on the wrong jobs.

Comment: @BN83 Add some sample input data and output data so I can check what is wrong with this query

Comment: See my comment to the OP's question. You can't use `GROUP BY` like this and expect consistent results.